# Error while loading data into DB2 (Issue in Bufferpool)

Tags: db2, bufferpool

For the past few days we are getting an while loading the data into DB2 Tables.

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-1218,
> SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=4096, DRIVER=4.24.92

I tried to check the actual reason and found it to be an issue in the buffer pool.

However, we tried creating additional buffer pools but the issue still exists.  Please help to fix this issue.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you looked up the [error message 1218](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql1000-sql1249)
the solution is right there as it says
"increase the bufferpool"

Alter the bufferpool to increase its size as described [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-alter-bufferpool).

Answer (score 0):

The bufferpool id (4096) in `SQLERRMC` means, that there is no pages in a tiny hidden bufferpool `IBMSYSTEMBP4K` of 16 4K pages. This bufferpool is assigned to a tablespace, when a bufferpool corresponding to this tablespace can't be started during the database activation. This can happen because of a configuration error or memory pressure in the system, for example.
You shouldn't create additional bufferpools, because it can't make DB2 use this bufferpool immediately for this tablespace. Drop these additional bufferpools you created. You can't enlarge this tiny hidden bufferpool as well.

The only thing you can do is to find this bufferpool, set its size accordingly and restart the database. The following query should help you to fine this bufferpool.

```
SELECT BPNAME, NPAGES
FROM SYSCAT.BUFFERPOOLS S
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM TABLE (MON_GET_BUFFERPOOL(NULL, -2)) M
WHERE M.BP_NAME = S.BPNAME
)
```

Run the following query for each bufferpool name in the result, for example. It sets the bufferpool size to 5000 pages (with an ability to grow if you have Self Tuning Memory Management enabled).

```
ALTER BUFFERPOOL bp_name_from_result SIZE 5000 AUTOMATIC
```

Restart the database afterwards (force all users off the database & run `deactivate db mydbname`). Check with the 1-st query again, if you still have some bufferpools not started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  Self Tuning memory management is not enabled in my system.  In this case, will the above steps help?

Comment: Yes, the steps are the same in your case.

Comment: I cleared all the bufferpools created newly and when I try to alter the bufferpools, I get this error.   ‪IWAQ0003W‬‎ ‪SQL‬‎ ‪warnings‬‎ ‪were‬‎ ‪found
‬‪SQLState‬‎=‪01654‬‎ ‪The‬‎ ‪buffer‬‎ ‪pool‬‎ ‪is‬‎ ‪not‬‎ ‪started‬‎.‪‬‎.‪‬‎ ‪SQLCODE‬‎=‪20169‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪SQLSTATE‬‎=‪01654‬‎,‪‬‎ ‪DRIVER‬‎=‪4‬‎.‪24‬‎.‪92  I tried multiple options like restarting the DB, deactivating the db to unlink the applications but nothing works.  
‬‪‬‎ ‪